# XM topology for on-premises

Tags: installation

What is the best practice for installing a XM only instance for dev locally? Should we just install XP0, and then disable xDB? There doesn't seem to be a XM single package, and when I try to install XM Scaled, it asks for a ssl cert, which we don't need for a local dev CM (I believe the XP0 doesn't need SSL for the CM).

Comment: Why disable xDB? There are a number of tutorials on installing 9 for dev locally. I always have it running with xDB running, otherwise how to do you develop xDB features? Also, nothing wrong with self-signed certs for local dev. Just follow these instructions: https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/11/The-lazy-way-to-install-Sitecore-9/

Comment: Yeah, I have XP0 installed, no issue. Client only has XM, so I want to replicate environment as best as possible.

Answer (score 5):

The Sitecore Experience Management configuration (CMS-only mode) running both the Content Delivery (CD) and Content Management (CM) roles. Use this environment when you are not planning to use the Analytics and Marketing features of the Sitecore Experience Platform. When you select this topology, xDB and xConnect are not available.

After selecting your deployment topology (XP0, XM1, or XP1), you must download the corresponding web
deploy packages which also contain the environment configuration files from the Sitecore Downloads page – https://dev.sitecore.net.

**The following Web Deploy Packages are required for XM1 topologies:**

- sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_cd.scwdp.zip
- sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_cm.scwdp.zip

**The following environment configuration files are required for XM1 topologies:**

- sitecore-solr.json
- sitecore-XM1-cd.json
- sitecore-XM1-cm.json

**If you want to install the XM0 topology, you only need to install the CM instance from the XM1 topology and then in the web.config file, specify the following setting:**

```
<add key="role:define" value="Standalone" />
```

You don't need "Client Certificates" and "SSL Certificate for Solr".

**Source:** Sitecore installation Guide.

Comment: Like you said, if you just want the XM you can just install XM without XP0. The SSL cert part in the installation, it will generate for you if you don't specify the SSL cert and left it blank.

Comment: Hello @navneet keshav

I am looking for the way to run sitecore with XM1 topologies.
I just only have:
- sitecore-solr.json
- sitecore-XM1-cd.json
- sitecore-XM1-cm.json
- Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_cd.scwdp.zip
- Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_cm.scwdp.zip

Could you please help me out a guide.
(all prerequisites have been installed)

I was following this guide https://buoctrenmay.com/2017/10/30/a-step-by-step-guide-for-sitecore-9-installation-on-your-machine/ but in the end I figured it out that it is for XPO install that I do not have now.

Thanks!